# How can we show that a Feller semigroup is strongly continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $C_0(E)$ denote the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity
- $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a contractive nonnegative semigroup on $C_0(E)$ with $$T_tf(x)\xrightarrow{t\to0}f(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\text{ and }f\in C_0(E)\tag1.$$

Why can we conclude from $(1)$ that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous?

Comment: I don't see where you have defined (1) .

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts $(1)$ is $$T_tf(x)\xrightarrow{t\to0}f(x)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\text{ and }f\in C_0(E)\tag1.$$

Comment: Did you check Ethier-Kurtz? Pretty sure that this is in there...

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I see now. I don't like the MathJax tag system because it appears way off to the right for me, and I don't notice it. Thanks.

Comment: @saz Ethier and Kurtz are defining a Feller semigroup to be $C^0$, but there is a proof in Kallenberg. However, he's proving the strong continuity using the Yosida approximation which in turn requires the existence of the generator and that it is densely-defined and closed. He's proving the existence by the properties of the Feller semigroup given in the question. I would like to do it the other way around: If we could prove the strong continuity directly, nothing of what he proves would be special anymore, since all of that are properties which are fulfilled by any $C^0$-semigroup.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I see.. well you could take a look at lemma 1.4 in "Levy Matters III" by Böttcher, Schilling & Wang.